# C - Close Thread

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I wrote client-server chat using threads (WindowsAPI) and non-blocking sockets.
When my client want to disconnect (by typing `quit`) I want to close the thread of the client. Thread is realized in client part, both server.c and client.c are in non-blocking mode.

I was recommended to use `WaitForSingleObject()` function and wrote this code:

```
        if (!strcmp(&bufferData[0], "quit\n"))
        {
            send(socketDescriptor, bufferData, strlen(&bufferData[0]), 0);
            printf("You just left the chat. Good bye\n");
            //break;
            running = false;
            int retwait = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 1000);
            if (retwait == 0)
            {
                printf("WaitForSingleObject error : Error code: %d", GetLastError());
                break;
            }
            if (shutdown(socketDescriptor, SD_BOTH) != 0)
            {
                printf("Shutdown SHUT_RDWR error");
            }
            break;
        }
```

I compare incoming buffer and what was typed in command line. If "quit" - close thread and shutdown.

Something's gone wrong because `WaitForSinglebject()` returns 0 every time and doesn't show error code (it's always 0). I used different parameters of this function (0, some value and wait forever).

What have I done wrong here?
Hope my question is provided to MCVE. Thanks

Comment: **IIRC (Don't hold me to this)** if the `main()` function of a thread returns, that thread ends; you can send a signal to that thread one way or another to tell it to simply `return 0;`. That's in Linux, not sure if this holds true in windows.

Comment: [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) returns `(DWORD)0xFFFFFFFF` on error not `0`.

Comment: You need to revisit the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx).

Comment: Could you [mcve]-ify this? Thanks.

Comment: `send(socketDescriptor, bufferData, strlen(&bufferData[0]), 0);` -- sending the length of the buffer alongside the buffer is the [Heartbleed](http://xkcd.com/1354/) bug.

Comment: *Something's gone wrong because WaitForSinglebject returns 0 every time and doesn't show error code (it's always 0)* When WaitForSingleObject returns with 0 that means everything went fine, which is confirmed with GetLastError result. Check the official documentation user IInspectable provided -> WAIT_OBJECT_0 = 
0x00000000L -> The state of the specified object is signaled. *What have I done wrong here?* Change if (retwait == 0) inro if (retwait != 0)

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: The return value of `GetLastError` is only meaningful in case `WaitForSingleObject` returns `WAIT_FAILED`. In case `WaitForSingleObject` returns anything else, the return value of `GetLastError` is meaningless. It does not confirm or refute anything.

Comment: Thank you all guys, well, I just though my stream couldn't be closed, I check the server's code and saw a little bug, now it's fine

Comment: @IInspectable: I agree with you, I just wanted to say that his `if` was wrong and that `WaitForSingleObject` did not fail...